# Why are Java 8 stream elements not being accessed sequentially?

Tags: java, java-stream

I created a piece of code which reads a String & creates a frequency map out of it. I came up with this in Java 8.

```
final Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>(26);
    myString.chars()
        .forEach(ch -> frequencyMap.put((char)ch, frequencyMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1));
```

However my output is as follows -

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I understand that the lambda functions can access only final/effectively final variables outside it's scope but here I don't seem to violate that rule as well.
I tried making the stream sequential explicitly by doing this but it still doesn't work

```
str.chars()
        .sequential().forEach(ch -> frequencyMap.put((char)ch, frequencyMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1));
```

To be sure that there isn't a problem with the way I'm using Map functions I tried the same map functions with array & it works -

```
final Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>(26);
    for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
      frequencyMap.put((char)ch, frequencyMap.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
    }
```

Output here -

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm aware of the many different solutions that exist to do this but I'm interested in knowing what concept I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the input string and what does the output mean? Dictionary is not array hence I don't understand how the numbers correspond to letters.

Comment: Typo, you missed casting at `.getOrDefault(ch, 0)` which should be `.getOrDefault((char)ch, 0)`. Otherwise `ch` represents `int` not `char` and since map doesn't hold Integers but Characters method always returns default value `0`.

Comment: Anyway you could rewrite your code into something more readable (at least IMO) like `Map<Character, Long> frequencyMap = myString.chars() .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`, This would also have benefit of not relying on maps which would be out of stream control.

Comment: Ahh sorry @orhtej2, Despite my best effort to be as verbose as I could be I missed telling that in my particular use case character identity corresponding to it's frequency is not required so I'm mapping just the frequencies to an array. So, it should have been frequency array I guess.

Comment: In a non-stream context, `frequencyMap.put((char)ch, frequencyMap.getOrDefault((char)ch, 0) + 1);` can be simplified to `frequencyMap.merge((char)ch, 1, Integer::sum);`, avoiding redundant operations. For a stream solution, see [@Pshemo’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646912/why-are-java-8-stream-elements-not-being-accessed-sequentially#comment112548925_63646912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea. Your initial code works if you also cast `ch` to char:

```
final Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>(26);
    myString.chars()
        .forEach(ch -> frequencyMap.put((char)ch, frequencyMap.getOrDefault((char)ch, 0) + 1));
```

If you omit this, the map key is a `java.lang.Character`. The search key is a `java.lang.Integer` and therefore they are not equal. This causes the count to stay 1 always.

Comment: After understanding the solution, it is also worthwhile to add that `ch` in case of `myString.toCharArray()` corresponds to an element of character array while `ch` in `str.chars()` corresponds to an element of IntStream. That's why it works in case of array without explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>(26);
myString.chars()
    .forEach(ch -> frequencyMap.compute((char)ch, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1));
```

Or

```
Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap = myString.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

Or

```
Map<Character, Long> frequencyMap = myString.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```